# Searching for a string with multiple words

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to find a specific string with 3 words in it using VBA. The string I am searching for is "Material Review Report". My code sort of works if I search for either "Material" or "Material Review" but when I try to search for the full string nothing is returned even though the string does exist in the document. It also won't find anything if I search for "Review Report" for example.
Here is my code:

```
Private Function getStringFromWord(strWordFile As String) As String
Dim appWord As Word.Application
Dim docWord As Word.Document
Dim strFind As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim rngDoc As Word.Range


Set appWord = New Word.Application
Set docWord = appWord.Documents.Open(strWordFile)

Set rngDoc = docWord.Content
With rngDoc.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .MatchWildcards = True
        'strFind = "Material" 'Works 
        'strFind = "Material Review" 'Works
         strFind = "Material Review Report" 'Does not work???
            .Text = strFind
            .Execute
            If .Found = True Then
                MsgBox "Found!"
            End If
End With

docWord.Close
    Set docWord = Nothing
appWord.Quit
    Set appWord = Nothing
End Function
```

So, what I am doing wrong here? Any help in pointing me to the right direction will be much appreciated.

Comment: Is there maybe an invisible char in your text? Does Word find the text if you enter the search term there?

Comment: @FunThomas: that's the thing that drives me crazy. Yes, when I search the same Word file it finds everything.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @FunThomas. There may be some unexpected white spaces between the words that happens when opening/importing text from PDF or other external sources. Try searching with any or all of these properties set to true

```
 .IgnorePunct = True
 .IgnoreSpace = True 
 .MatchPhrase = True
```

Browse https://www.codevba.com/Word/Find.htm#.YgEsB5qZMuU for more.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am trying out the properties you mentioned but so far no luck with them either. For what is worth, this is indeed a Word file created from a PDF export

Comment: Check that strange char between "Review" and "Report" that looks a " " (`Chr(32)` ) but it is not. If it is e.g a tab char then change the search term to that.